# is there any schema documentation for JOOQ's maven configuration?

Tags: java, jooq

all the documentation i see on JOOQ's maven config shows various examples.

Is there any page that lists the entire schema and documents individual elements?

I dont want to go through the entire list of examples to find out the elements i need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a corresponding XSD. Here you find the [XSD for version 3.12](https://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.12.0.xsd). For other versions you can browse https://www.jooq.org/xsd/.